# AMC for the aerospike server running inside docker

Tags: aerospike, aerospike-loader

I have run the aerospike server inside docker container using below command.

```
  $  docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 -p 3002:3002 -p 3003:3003  -p 8081:8081  --name aerospike aerospike/aerospike-server
  89b29f48c6bce29045ea0d9b033cd152956af6d7d76a9f8ec650067350cbc906
```

It is running succesfully. I verified it using the below command.

```
 $ docker ps
 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                
 CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                                      
 NAMES
 89b29f48c6bc        aerospike/aerospike-server   "/entrypoint.sh asd"    
 About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:3000-3003->3000-3003/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp   aerospike
```

I'm able to successfully connect it with `aql`.

```
$ aql
Aerospike Query Client
Version 3.13.0.1
C Client Version 4.1.6
Copyright 2012-2016 Aerospike. All rights reserved.
aql>
```

But when I launch the AMC for aerospike server in docker, it is hanging and it is not displaying any data. I've attached the screenshot.

[image: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE]

Did I miss any configuration. Why it is not loading any data?

Comment: Are popups enabled in the browser? Looks like you do have amc server running but its not going to next step of opening the dialog box to enter server ip:port.

Comment: seems like the browser displayed the due to cache. When I clear cache and reload it displayed ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. I've updated the question section.

Comment: Did you start the AMC server? $ sudo service amc start

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  aerospike:
    image: "aerospike:ce-6.0.0.1"
    environment:
      NAMESPACE: testns
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3001:3001"
      - "3002:3002"
  amc:
    image: "aerospike/amc"
    links:
      - "aerospike:aerospike"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

Then go to http://localhost:8081 and enter in the connect window "**aerospike:3000**"